# Prove if $d|b$ then $b=cd$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove the following statement or give a counterexample.

If $d$ is any counting number and $d|b$, then there is a counting number $c$ such that $b=cd$.

This was my attempt at proving this. Am I on the right track?

Let $d|b$, then by quotient-remainder theorem: $$\frac bd= q=c \left[c=\frac bd\right]$$

Comment: that is how i define that symbol. How do you?

Comment: You could put directly $c$ instead of $q$

Comment: That is the definition of the symbol $\mid$ so there is nothing to prove...

Comment: Are counting numbers the same as positive numbers? Is $b$ positive or $b\in\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Counting numbers are positive natural numbers..{1,2,3...}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of $b\mid d$ is that there exists $k\in\Bbb{Z},$ so that $bk=d.$ Just use $c$ instead of $k.$